# "Hidden" variable in Simulink models

Tags: matlab, simulink

Some example models that are included in the Simulink library, there are some variables that their value is not visible. For instance, in the model power_PVarray_grid_det the sample time of the powergui is defined as Ts_Power. I can not figure out the value of this variable. Is there a way to find these hidden variables, have access to them and change their value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click the `File/Model Properties/Model Properties` item in the model window menu
2. Select the `Callbacks` tab in the model properties dialog window

Then you can see that the `PreLoadFcn` callback is defined as follows: [image]

This code is executed before the model is loaded, so `Ts_Power` is initialized to 10^-6.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if there is a way to edit these variables through command line or a script?

Comment: I was about to post this. Save the example locally and remove those variables out of the callback.

Comment: You can also call your own script from the callback